# Android API 24 < Crashes with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher

Tags: java, android, gradle, google-cloud-firestore

My app is crashing everytime it starts up with: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher`. This only happens on devices running below android API 24. I have tried amending the Gradle versions and plugins as well as including the `com.google.guava` dependency but it did not work. Here is the full stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.base.CharMatcher
    at com.google.common.base.Splitter.on(Splitter.java:127)
    at io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil.<clinit>(GrpcUtil.java:197)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.<clinit>(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:90)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget(OkHttpChannelProvider.java:46)
    at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget(OkHttpChannelProvider.java:26)
    at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(ManagedChannelBuilder.java:76)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.initChannel(GrpcCallProvider.java:113)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.lambda$initChannelTask$6(GrpcCallProvider.java:256)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider$$Lambda$5.call(GrpcCallProvider.java)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzy.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.1.0:2)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ThrottledForwardingExecutor.java:54)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor$$Lambda$1.run(ThrottledForwardingExecutor.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I also get this exception constantly along with the above one:

```
W/System.err: io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelBuilder
        at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:69)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelBuilder
```

My project level gradle file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
    classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.0"
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.1'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1'  // Performance Monitoring plugin
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

This is my app level gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id("com.github.triplet.play") version "2.8.0"
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 48
        versionName "4.0.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            ...
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors{
        spanish{
            dimension "version"
            applicationId "..."
            buildConfigField 'String', 'PRIMARY_COLOR', '"#ffc400"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'ACCENT_COLOR', '"#C60B1E"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'LANG_CODE', '"es"'
        }
        italian{
            dimension "version"
            applicationId "..."
            buildConfigField 'String', 'PRIMARY_COLOR', '"#008C45"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'ACCENT_COLOR', '"#CD212A"'
            buildConfigField 'String', 'LANG_CODE', '"it"'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}

play {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    //debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.0-beta-5'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.7.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.1.1'
    implementation 'br.com.simplepass:loading-button-android:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:19.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-android'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
```

Comment: can you post your app level build.gradle?

Comment: @HayssamSoussi sure, it's kinda big though

Comment: just post the implementations

Comment: @HayssamSoussi posted

Comment: okay, removing `implementation 'com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:2.8.0'` fixes the issue. But I don't want to remove this dependency :/

Comment: Try to keep it and change guava version to 28.0

Answer (score 2):

If you replace

```
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-android'
```

for this

```
implementation ('com.google.guava:guava') {
    version {
        strictly '29.0-android'
    }
}
```

it should work.